# How to replace a null value from a pandas dataframe with a non-null value from the same column in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, database

For example:

[image: A certain group]

I need to replace the NaN values for rows under HomePlanet column with the most frequent entries in the other rows (in this case it would be Earth). How can I go about executing this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for (assuming your dataframe is named 'df')?

df["HomePlanet"].fillna("Earth", inplace = True)

Comment: So It can be some other planet, like Europa, Mars, etc. I didn't quite clear my question. My bad. Basically, There are a bunch of people who are divided into some groups. But, for some reason, a few of the passengers belonging to a group have 'NaN' as their home planet. So I was trying to replace their "NaN" values with the HomePlanet entry given to the fellow group members.